# SharePoint Search - "Did you mean" functionality

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I have the following queries about the "Did you mean" auto spell check functionality in SharePoint Online Search -

- How is the dictionary of words used for the spell check
  being built and is the dictionary expanded as more content is being
  crawled? Is there a dictionary per language?
- Is it possible to look at this dictionary somehow? (Powershell?)
- How does the Did you
  mean functionality work for languages other than English? What
  languages are supported?
- Does it correct the spelling based on the number of times the keyword is available in the content? What is the minimum number of keywords existent in the content for Did you mean to work?
- Is it based on a keyword existent in the dictionary?
- Is it based in both, frequency of the word and keyword?
- How and how often is the Microsoft dictionary being updated?
- When is it necessary to add a keyword to the Search Dictionaries term set?

I could not find this information in the official MS documentation and hence reaching out to see if someone would know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could manage query spelling by going to tenant admin center->search->Manage Search Dictionaries, [official guideline](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-search-dictionaries-2d0ee673-02f1-4b52-9159-f743b5123460) or [official guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/manage-query-spelling-correction)

[supported language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/linguistic-search-features)

Comment: Thank you Lee for the reply. The first link you provided gives more insight into the functionality. However I have some specific queries. Editing my original question to include these.

Comment: I found this link to have very useful information about this functionality that I could not find elsewhere - http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/03/sharepoint-2013-search-spelling.html